# In my class i have to creating a method to find multiple maximum numbers in an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

In my class i have to create a method that will find multiple maximum numbers within an array.  the user will input how many maximum numbers they are wanting and then the code should display all those numbers.  if i select 2 this code will show me the 2 maximum numbers but if im wanting more it just doesnt work.  i was trying to search the array for the maximum number and then have it display the outcome and then change that element to 0 and than repeat the loop until it hits that number (userinput).  im soo frustrated can someone help me please

```
    public static int FindingMaxNum(int[] arr, int max)
    { 
        int userinput;
        Console.Write("Enter the number of maximum values: ");
        userinput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

        int i = 0;
        int c = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        { 
         if (arr[i] >= max)
         {
             max = arr[i];
             c++;

             while (c <= userinput)
             {
                Console.WriteLine(max);
                arr[i] = 0;
                break;
             }
          }

        }
        return -1;
     }
```

Comment: If you can use LINQ, its a 2 liner: `foreach (var val in arr.OrderByDescending(i => i).Take(max)) Console.WriteLine(val);`

Comment: i have no idea what that is sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get some number of items from an array whose values are greater than all the others in the array.

If so, something like this modified version of your method may do the trick:

```
public static void WriteMaxNum(int[] arr)
{
    if (arr == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The array is null");
        return;
    }

    if (arr.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The array is empty");
        return;
    }

    int count = arr.Length;
    int numMaxValues;

    // Get number of max values to return from user
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the number of maximum values (1 - {0}): ", count);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numMaxValues) ||
             numMaxValues < 1 ||
             numMaxValues > count);

    // Output the max values
    Console.Write("The {0} max values are: ", numMaxValues);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", arr.OrderByDescending(i => i).Take(numMaxValues)));
}
```

**Usage**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myArray = new[] { 1, 9, 4, 8, 2, 5, 0, 7, 6, 3 };
    WriteMaxNum(myArray);

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: i have a random array set up and i need a user to input the number of maximum numbers they want to display on the screen.  so if the user wants to see 3 of the maximum values within that array the program will display it.

Comment: I changed it to write out the values instead of returning them.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with average complexity O(nlogn):
Sort the array first then print the last N nos.

```
 int[] arr = new int[]{-5,-69,1250,24,-96,32578,11,124};
   Array.Sort(arr);
   int n=3;
   for(int i=arr.Length-1;i>=0 && n>0 ;--i){
       n--;
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
   }
```

Now coming to your code, there are multiple problems. First there is no need to take 'max' as parameter in your function. Second you are looping only arr.Length times once. There should be nested loop, outer one of which has to run userInput times and inner on has to iterate over all the values. Third you should initialize to extracted value position to minimum value so that the method works for negative numbers too.

Refined code:

```
 for(int i=0;i<userinput;++i){
        int max = int.MinValue,pos=-1;
        for(int j=0;j<arr.Length;++j){
            if(max<arr[j]){
                pos = j;
                max = arr[j];
            }
        }
        arr[pos] = int.MinValue;
        Console.Write(max+",");
    }
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use the int.MinValue,pos=-1. What does it mean.y have you used it

Comment: those are two different statements: int max = int.MinValue; which is to initialise the value of max as lowest value possible for int. This will ensure that if there is a number -1 in  {-5,-1,-3} then -1>max otherwise if you keep it 0 then there will be no max values in the array.
pos = -1; // forget -1 as of now. pos variable finds the index where max value was found. It is used later to make the value int.MinValue(replacing your 0 idea).

Comment: when i run this code, after the user inputs a number this part is highlighted arr[pos] = int.MinValue; with an error message saying "make sure that the maximum index on a list is less than the list size" also this puts it in order. i am only wanting it to display the number of maximum values the user inputs, so if i want 2 max numbers it will only display 2